# How to get the level of a leaf in a non-binary tree

Tags: java, tree

I have constructed a Tree class as shown below:

```
public class Node {

    private int label;
    private ArrayList<Node> children;
    private Node parent;

    public Node(int label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.parent = null;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public int getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

Assuming that I have a non binary Tree:

```
    1
    |
    9
 /  |  \
3   0   7
```

How can I write a method in order to get the level of a leaf (say node labelled with `7`) in a non-binary Tree?

```
    public int getLevel() {
        if (parent == null) return 0;

         // Additional code is needed here  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `level` is often called the depth or height.

```
public int getLevel(){
    Node temp = parent;
    int depth = 0;
    while(temp != null){
        depth++;
        temp = temp.parent;
    }
    return depth;
}
```

This will not work if there is a cycle of course, but there shouldn't be one in a tree anyways.